# Passing lambda instead of interface

Tags: lambda, kotlin

I have created an interface:

```
interface ProgressListener {
    fun transferred(bytesUploaded: Long)
}
```

but can use it only as an anonymous class, not lambda

```
dataManager.createAndSubmitSendIt(title, message,
object : ProgressListener {
    override fun transferred(bytesUploaded: Long) {
        System.out.println(bytesUploaded.toString())
    }
})
```

I think it should be a possibility to replace it by lambda:

```
dataManager.createAndSubmitSendIt(title, message, {System.out.println(it.toString())})
```

But I am getting error: `Type mismatch; required - ProgressListener, found - () -> Unit?`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

As @zsmb13 said, SAM conversions are only supported for Java interfaces.

You could create an extension function to make it work though:

```
// Assuming the type of dataManager is DataManager.
fun DataManager.createAndSubmitSendIt(title: String, 
                                      message: String, 
                                      progressListener: (Long) -> Unit) {
    createAndSubmitSendIt(title, message,
        object : ProgressListener {
            override fun transferred(bytesUploaded: Long) {
                progressListener(bytesUploaded)
            }
        })
}
```

#### Edit

Kotlin 1.4 introduced function interfaces that enable SAM conversions for interfaces defined in Kotlin. This means that you can call your function with a lambda if you define your interface with the `fun` keyword. Like this:

```
fun interface ProgressListener {
    fun transferred(bytesUploaded: Long)
}
```

Comment: `fun interface` - truer words were hardly ever written.

Comment: yes `fun interface` this will make the normal interface to functional interface.

Answer (score 34):

Update: you need to use a [`fun interface`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html) to support SAM conversions, which let you pass in a lambda as the implementation of an interface.

Old answer below.

---

Kotlin only supports SAM conversions for Java interfaces.

> ... note that this feature works only for Java interop; since Kotlin
> has proper function types, automatic conversion of functions into
> implementations of Kotlin interfaces is unnecessary and therefore
> unsupported.

-- [Official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions)

If you want to use a lambda in the parameter, make your function take a function parameter instead of an interface. (For now at least. Supporting SAM conversions for Kotlin interfaces is an ongoing discussion, it was one of the possible future features at the Kotlin 1.1 live stream.)

Comment: Probably it's also worth mentioning that, if the original intention of the interface was to express the semantics of the expected function, then you can use [typealiases](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew11.html#type-aliases) or functional types with named parameters like `(bytesUploaded: Long) -> Unit`.

Comment: This answer is outdated. SAM conversions for Kotlin interfaces is supported as of Kotlin 1.4. See @marstan's edited answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43470351/1071320).

Answer (score 16):

**UPDATED: September 7th, 2020**

As the Kotlin [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew14.html#sam-conversions-for-kotlin-interfaces) for the Kotlin 1.4 release points out:

> Before Kotlin 1.4.0, you could apply SAM (Single Abstract Method) conversions only when working with Java methods and Java interfaces from Kotlin. From now on, you can use SAM conversions for Kotlin interfaces as well. To do so, mark a Kotlin interface explicitly as functional with the fun modifier.

```
fun interface Operation1 {
    operator fun invoke(x: String): String
}

fun interface Operation2 {
    fun doSomething(x: Int): String
}

val operation1 = Operation1 { "$it world!" }
val operation2 = Operation2 { "$it world!" }

fun main() {
    // Usage: First sample.
    println(operation1("Hello"))
    println(operation2.doSomething(0))
    // Usage: Second sample.
    println(Operation1 { "$it world!" }("Hello"))
    println(Operation2 { "$it!" }.doSomething(0))
}
```

You can read more about functional interfaces [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/fun-interfaces.html).

**Previous solution:**

Declare a typealias, inject it somewhere and invoke it later on:

```
internal typealias WhateverListener = (String) -> Unit
```

and then we inject that typealias to our class:

```
class Gallery constructor(private val whateverListener: WhateverListener) {
    
    ...
    
    galleryItemClickListener.invoke("hello")

    ...
}
```

so we have our lambda:

```
val gallery = Gallery { appNavigator.openVideoPlayer(it) }
```

Credits to my colleague Joel Pedraza, who showed me the trick while trying to find a solution <3.

**NOTE: Check out the [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/fun-interfaces.html#functional-interfaces-vs-type-aliases) in case you want to know when to use either functional interfaces (lambdas) or type aliases.**

Comment: This is a nice solution and you don't even need that extra `typealias`.

Comment: Nested and local typealiases are not supported

Answer (score 12):

## Kotlin 1.4 and after

Kotlin 1.4 will fix this problem via "Functional Interfaces"

### Kotlin Functional Interface

> - Kotlin API: Perfect
> - Kotlin Access: Perfect
> - Java Access: Perfect

```
class KotlinApi {
    fun interface Listener {
        fun onResponse(response: String)
    }

    fun demo(listener: Listener) {
        listener.onResponse("response")
    }
}

fun kotlinConsumer() {
    KotlinApi().demo { response ->
        println(response)
    }
}

public static void javaConsumer(){
    new KotlinApi().demo(response -> {
        System.out.println(response);
    });
}
```

## Before Kotlin 1.4

There is no single ultimate solution for this problem if you are aiming best access experience from both Kotlin and Java.

If Kotlin developers had not thought SAM conversion for Kotlin interfaces is unnecessary, "Kotlin Interface" method would be ultimate solution.

> https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions
>   Also note that this feature works only for Java interop; since Kotlin
>   has proper function types, automatic conversion of functions into
>   implementations of Kotlin interfaces is unnecessary and therefore
>   unsupported.

Select the best solution for your use case.

### Kotlin Function Type

> - Kotlin API: Perfect
> - Kotlin Access: Perfect
> - Java Access:
>
>   - Auto generated parameter type like Function1 (not a big problem for Java 8 lambda)
>   - Verbose `return Unit.INSTANCE;` instead of void return.

```
class KotlinApi {
    fun demo(listener: (response: String) -> Unit) {
       listener("response")
    }
}

fun kotlinConsumer() {
    KotlinApi().demo { response->
        println(response)
    }
}

public static void javaConsumer() {
    new KotlinApi().demo(response -> {
        System.out.println(response);
        return Unit.INSTANCE;
    });
}
```

### Kotlin Interface

> - Kotlin API: Additional interface definition.
> - Kotlin Access: Too verbose
> - Java Access: Perfect

```
class KotlinApi {
    interface Listener {
        fun onResponse(response: String)
    }

    fun demo(listener: Listener) {
       listener.onResponse("response")
    }
}

fun kotlinConsumer() {
    KotlinApi().demo(object : KotlinApi.Listener {
        override fun onResponse(response: String) {
            println(response)
        }
    })
}

public static void javaConsumer() {
    new KotlinApi().demo(response -> {
        System.out.println(response);
    });
}
```

### Java Interface

> - Kotlin API: Mixed Java code.
> - Kotlin Access: A little verbose
> - Java Access: Perfect

```
class KotlinApi {
    fun demo(listener: Listener) {
        listener.onResponse("response")
    }
}

public interface Listener {
    void onResponse(String response);
}

fun kotlinConsumer() {
    KotlinApi().demo { response ->
        println(response)
    }
}

public static void javaConsumer() {
    new KotlinApi().demo(response -> {
        System.out.println(response);
    });
}
```

### Multiple Methods

> - Kotlin API: Multiple method implementations
> - Kotlin Access: Perfect if correct method is used. Auto completion suggests verbose method also.
> - Java Access: Perfect. Auto completion does not suggest function type method because of `JvmSynthetic` annotation

```
class KotlinApi {
    interface Listener {
        fun onResponse(response: String)
    }

    fun demo(listener: Listener) {
        demo { response ->
            listener.onResponse(response)
        }
    }

    @JvmSynthetic //Prevents JVM to use this method
    fun demo(listener: (String) -> Unit) {
        listener("response")
    }
}

fun kotlinConsumer() {
    KotlinApi().demo { response ->
        println(response)
    }
}

public static void javaConsumer() {
    new KotlinApi().demo(response -> {
        System.out.println(response);
    });
}
```

### Java API

> - Kotlin API: There is no Kotlin API, all API code is Java
> - Kotlin access: Perfect
> - Java access: Perfect

```
public class JavaApi {
    public void demo(Listener listener) {
        listener.onResponse("response");
    }

    public interface Listener {
        void onResponse(String response);
    }

}

fun kotlinConsumer() {
    JavaApi().demo { response ->
        println(response)
    }
}

public static void javaConsumer() {
    new JavaApi().demo(response -> {
        System.out.println(response);
    });
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for the java examples. I had problem what should I return when high order function return Unit.

Answer (score 10):

A little late to the party: instead of making an interface, you let the compile create one by taking a function directly instead of an interface in your datamanager, like this:

```
fun createAndSubmitSendIt(title: String, message: String, transferred: (Long) -> Unit) {
    val answer = TODO("whatever you need to do")
    transferred(answer)
}
```

and then you just use it like how you want it! If I remember correctly, what the kotlin/jvm compiler do is the same as making an interface.

Hope it helps!